# Google Cloud NAT with Shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to deploy the Elasticsearch application on Kubernetes Engine for company internal usage. Currently, there is interconnect with the Google Shared VPC project. I am new to GCP and I don't really know what is the best approach to deploy this application network wise. I am considering to approach that I am not sure if It is event possible for now(hence, the question arises).

1.) Can I use Native VPN for Elasticserach project and do some kind of NAT to Shared VPC IP so the Networks would now overly with the corporate ones.

2.) Should I Just use network acquired from Shard VPC for Kubernetes Network and It should work? What size for the subnet would I need?

Answer (score 0):

I got It works by:

1.) making a linux based VM with 2 nic interfaces. First one with IP from the Shared VPC network and another one from Project VPC Network.

2.) Added in Kubernetes private cluster IP of the VM from the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on your answer and how you got this to work? Was your private GKE cluster created on the shared vpc subnet? What do you mean by "Added in Kubernetes private cluster IP of the VM from the same project"?

I have created a private gke cluster on shared vpc but can't reach the internet.